# md5 file checksum from specific bytes

Tags: java, byte, md5, checksum

I want to create a md5 checksum from specific bytes from file.
checksum will be from 100 bytes from file.

I write this code:

```
public static String getMD5ChecksumByFlash(String filename) throws Exception {
    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
    MessageDigest complete = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

    int passes = fis.available() / 100;
    int currentOffset = 0;
    int readBytes = -1;

    do {
        System.out.println("0a "+currentOffset);
        System.out.println("0b "+readBytes);
        readBytes = fis.read(buffer, currentOffset, 1);
        System.out.println("1 "+currentOffset);
        System.out.println("2 "+readBytes);
        if ( readBytes!=-1 ) {
            complete.update(buffer, 0, readBytes);
            currentOffset += passes;
            System.out.println("4 "+readBytes);
        }
        System.out.println("3 "+currentOffset);
        System.out.println("5 "+readBytes);
    } while ( readBytes!=-1 );
    fis.close();

    byte[] b = complete.digest();
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        result += Integer.toString((b[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

but it doesn't work :/
It returns:

```
0a 0
0b -1
1 0
2 1
4 1
3 93928
5 1
0a 93928
0b 1
null
```

What's wrong?

PS.
This file isn't 1byte file - it's pidgin-2.10.1.exe

Comment: can't make any sense of your code. buffer is a 1 long array, so I have no idea what you're trying to do with `currentOffset`. You should probably read the javadocs more carefully.

Comment: The code makes sense. It tries to read one byte at a time into a buffer, at positions 0, (filesize*1/10), (filesize*2/10) and so on, to create the MD5 sum of 100 bytes from various offsets. But it seems Java has some problems seeking from file offset 0 to file offset 93928.

Comment: @schnaader - yes, you are right. That's my intention :) Here you have whole java file - http://pastebin.com/axeGiJ4B

Comment: You realise you're still only going to read from the very start of the file, right? You're not seeking or anything like that...

Comment: @Jon: Looking at the documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29 , this should seek because `currentOffset` is passed to the `read` function.

Comment: @schnaader: that is the offset into the byte array, not the file. And the byte array is only 1 long, so it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @schnaader Read the documentation again. The `off` parameter is the offset into the byte array not into the file. (funnily enough, the function below it is exactly what you want)

Comment: Ah, that'd make sense. In this case it's just the documentation being quite confusing as it doesn't clearly state this.

Comment: It doesn't make sens `b` - the buffer into which the data is read, and the `off` and `len` is corespondind to the `b`? It doesnt make sens reading from `b` and writing to the same array.

Comment: It's not reading from `b`, but from the file. To put it in (hopefully) clear words, it's a function that reads `len` bytes from the actual position of the file into `b[off]` - which doesn't make sense for a 1-byte buffer and imho is misleading as usually a file offset is passed to a read function and even after reading the documentation again, I can't see a clear statement anywhere that `off` is related to `b`.

Comment: @schnaader Try the current documentation and not the almost 10year old one. In the current version for JDK7 it says: `off - the start offset in the destination array b`

Comment: @Voo: Thanks, that one is much better ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29 ) - that was a case of relying on Google too much that returns the old documentation as the first result - lesson learned :)

Comment: @schnaader Yeah usually you get at least the java5 or 6 documentation which is mostly identical to the one in 7. But 1.4.2 is reaally ancient if you think about it (no enums, no generics,..) - that's the problem with google. Even worse if you're searching for the python3 documentation - even when explicitly searching for  "python3" you more often than not get the python2 version ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some clarifications in the comments, it looks like the offset passed to the `read` function specifies the offset in the *array*, not the *file*. That's why you're getting `null` there and an exception is thrown. So you could correct the code by replacing the `read` call with this:

```
readBytes = fis.read(buffer, 0, 1);
fis.skip(passes - 1);
```

A slightly different, more complete approach would be:

```
public static String getMD5ChecksumByFlash(String filename) throws Exception {
    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
    MessageDigest complete = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

    int passes = fis.available() / 100;
    int currentOffset = 0;
    int readBytes = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        readBytes += fis.read(buffer, i, 1);
        // TODO: Check for I/O errors
        fis.skip(passes - 1);
    }
    fis.close();

    complete.update(buffer, 0, readBytes);

    byte[] b = complete.digest();
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        result += Integer.toString((b[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok just a simple approach, without all the error checking, looping and the size check you'd need for a reliable solution. This reads 1 byte every 100byte into the bytebuffer.

```
byte[] arr = new byte[100];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    is.read(arr, i, 1);
    is.skip(99);
}
```